# How to update AndroidSDK tools using Nexus Repository Manager

Tags: android, nexus, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to update build-tools for AndroidSDK. My machine locate in private network and we using Nexus Repository Manager. I have proxy repository to `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/repository` and I can manually download for example `https://nexus-ci.company/repository/proxy-group/addons_list-3.xml`.

Also I know about **SDK_TEST_BASE_URL** environment variable, so I can override repository for resources.
My variable:

```
export SDK_TEST_BASE_URL=https://ci_dos_user:*******@nexus-ci.company/repository/proxy-group/
```

So yes, only way I can connect - with credentials.

But when I put path to my proxy repository I have error log:

```
Warning: IO exception while downloading manifest
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL: https://ci_dos_user:*******@nexus-ci.company/repository/proxy-group/repository2-1.xml
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1932)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1528)
at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:224)
at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openUrl(DownloadCache.java:248)
at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.downloadAndCache(DownloadCache.java:624)
at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.remote.internal.DownloadCache.openCachedUrl(DownloadCache.java:547)
at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.LegacyDownloader.downloadAndStream(LegacyDownloader.java:61)
at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RemoteRepoLoaderImpl.lambda$fetchPackages$0(RemoteRepoLoaderImpl.java:139)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

How can I update my build-tools using nexus?

P.S.
I also know about --proxy flags to sdkmanager. But I have not access to proxy on my machine.